# Find closed form of 1st order recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I am trying to find a closed form of the following recurrence relation. $a_n, b_n, s_n, X_0$ are given for all $n$.

\begin{equation}
X_{n+1} = a_n(1 - s_n^2) +  s_n^2\frac{X_n + b_n}{2} + s_n\frac{|X_n - b_n|}{2}
\end{equation}

If there is no closed form, how could I approach a proof?

Comment: With some substitutions you can write $Y_{n+1}=A_nY_n+B_n|Y_n|+C_n$ where $A_n,B_n,C_n$ only depend on $a_n,b_n,s_n$. I think the absolute value will prohibit any nice closed form in general.

Comment: I have the same impression. How would I go about starting a proof?